# Masking part of the string with a regex

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

The idea is to mask a string like it's done with a credit cards. It can be done with this one line of code. And it works. However I can't find any straightforward explanations of the regex used in this case.

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String t1 = "518798673672531762319871";
        System.out.println(t1.replaceAll(".(?=.{4})", "*"));
    }
}
```

Output is: `********************9871`

Comment: You have explanation [here](https://regex101.com/r/WZLn23/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Explanation** of regex:

```
.(?=.{4})
```

- `.`: Match any character
- `(?=`: Start of a lookahead condition

  - `.{4}`: that asserts presence of 4 characters
- `)`: End of the lookahead condition

In simple words it matches any character in input that has 4 characters on right hand side of the current position.

Replacement is `"*"` which means for each matched character in inout, replace by a single `*` character, thus replacing all the characters in credit card number except the last 4 characters when lookahead condition fails the match (since we won't have 4 characters ahead of current position).

[Read more on look arounds in regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 2):

`?=.{4}` is a positive lookahead. it matches the pattern inside the brackets (the next 4 digits after the current character) without including it in the main result (the `.` outside the brackets) that is matching all the other characters for replacement by *

Conceive that your regex goes through the input char by char. On the first digit (5) it asks "is there a single char followed by 4 other chars? yes, ok.. replace [the 5] with *"

It repeats this until the 9 (4th from end, at which point the "is there another 4 characters after this?" question becomes "no" and the replacing stops